# Convert DetAnnotation in a loop with `stimcirq`

Tags: stim

Is there any workaround to convert the DetAnnotation in a `cirq` repetition block to the detector in the `stim` repeat block?

It seems `stimcirq` prevent this on purpose. But I want to use the MeasurementKey to make the detector adding easier while keeping the compact block style in generated stim circuit.

Comment: Could you include an example circuit that's not working? `DetAnnotation` is intended to convert correctly even in loops.

Comment: I found out it was the `DetAnnotation` with parity_keys using a specific repetition id that broke down. The error message said, " Measurement key conversion is not reliable when loops are present". Should I use relative keys within the loop to get over it?

Comment: Yes, you should use relative keys.